# Binary Plist Serializing/Deserializing using C#

Tags: c#, binary, plist

I have an iPhone client talking to a Windows server written in C#.The data from the device is sent as a binary plist.I am looking for a framework in C# that understands the binary plist and converts it into a dataset. On googling, I ran into plutil but that's a CLI and I need something that does it inline with the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Plist serialization and de-serialization for C# and .NET.](https://github.com/ChadBurggraf/plists-cs)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of any library for Windows that does this. But you might want to take the [property list reading code from The Cocotron](http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSPropertyList/NSPropertyListReader_binary1.m) and port it to C#. It shouldn’t be too hard to do that.

Comment: Fascinating .. Cocotron.  I did not know about that.  Thanks.

Comment: Any one has a solution? I don't really know what to do with the link posted by @Sven